# Jquery datepicker add click event to prev next button

Tags: jquery, events, datepicker, click

I have this function that will set a datepicker for a given element id and i'm trying to add a click function to prev and next buttons. But nothing seems to work. I have searched the web for adding click events to these buttons but they are all giving an id.

What i'm doing wrong here ?

```
function setDatepicker(element,curdate,identifier){
    //identifier is the element.id
    var minDateMaxDate = getCalendarsYearRange(1);
    var min = new Date(minDateMaxDate[0] * 1000);
    var max = new Date(minDateMaxDate[1] * 1000);

    $(element).datepicker({
          id: identifier,                 
          firstDay: 1,
          showOtherMonths: false,
          selectOtherMonths: false,
          changeYear: true,
          changeMonth: true,
          yearRange: getCalendarsYearRange(0),
          monthNamesShort:monthNamesShort,
          dayNamesShort:dayNamesShort,
          minDate: min,
          maxDate: max,
          onClose: function (dateText, inst){
            saveFieldsChanges(element,dateText,inst);
            getFieldsFromDialog();
          }
    });

    $(element).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy" );
    $(element).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", curdate );  
    $("#"+identifier+" .ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-header .ui-datepicker-prev").live('click', function(){     
        console.log("prev");
    });
    $("#"+identifier+" .ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-header .ui-datepicker-next").live('click', function(){     
        console.log("next");
    });

}
```

**Update**

Html where i set the datepicker, this is part of a xsl template that is loaded, the input fields are the datepickers.

```
<div class="ferias-form-div">

        <div class="labelfieldcontainer">
            <div class="formlabels">Data início</div>
            <div class="formfields">
                <input type="text" id="datainicioferias" onblur="saveFieldsChanges(this)" onkeyup="saveFieldsChanges(this)" name="datainicioferias" value="" class="textbox"/>
                <div class="errodialog" id="datainiciodialogferias"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="labelfieldcontainer">
            <div class="formlabels">Data fim</div>
            <div class="formfields">
                <input type="text" id="datafinalferias" onblur="saveFieldsChanges(this)" onkeyup="saveFieldsChanges(this)" name="datafinalferias" value="" class="textbox"/>
                <div class="errodialog" id="datafimdialogferias"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
...
```

This is how i set the datepicker for example:

```
setDatepicker(inputelement,curdate,"datafinalferias");
```

**UPDATE 2 - With answear**

With the help from **Alexander** i added this option to the calendar

```
onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst ) {

            var limites;
            var cal_date_string = month+'/'+year;           
            limites = getCalendarsYearRange(2); //my calendar's navigation limits
            var end_date_string = limites[1]; //my calendar's navigation limits
            var start_date_string = limites[0]; //my calendar's navigation limits

            if(end_date_string == cal_date_string){         
                setTimeout( function(){ $(".ui-datepicker-next").attr( "onclick", 'mensagemLimite(1);' )},100);
            }

            if(start_date_string == cal_date_string){ 
                setTimeout( function(){ $(".ui-datepicker-prev").attr( "onclick", 'mensagemLimite(0);' )},100);
            }

          }
```

This way when the prev/next button gets inactive it will get the onclick function i want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-next', function () {
  console.log('next');  
})

$(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-prev', function () {
  console.log('prev');  
})
```

Comment: How can I prevents click effects on body, because whenever I click on arrow, my sidebar going to close Here is the video https://www.loom.com/share/a1f8bff0463e45d782b623f196d9ffce